# How to merge two different url for parsing using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, getjson

i want to try make parse with two different url but I my code not works:
I have tried two different examples:

```
   var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=15&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";
var url2 = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";

$.when($.getJSON(url), $.getJSON(url2)).done(function (data1, data2) {

    alert(data1.address.village);
    alert(data2.address.city);

    //do stuff with 'data' and 'data2'
});


$.getJSON("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311", function (data) {
    $.getJSON("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311", function (data2) {
        var concatenatedJson = $.extend({}, data, data2);

        alert(concatenatedJson.address.road);

    });
});
```

Comment: you can easily inspect what's in `data1`... it's an array, not the object from the URL ... your alert should be `data1[0].address.village` and `data2[0].address.city` as [showned here](https://i.imgur.com/AbtRxaz.png)

Comment: Where is data1 and data2 coming from? You may want to read up on how `getJson()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only wrong you're doing is **assuming** the data you are receiving

a simple `console.log(data1)` would be suffice to tell you that the data received in `data1` is not the data from the URL, but an array with a bit more information

[image]
all you need is to point to the correct Array and all will be working as you wanted:

```js
var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=15&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";
var url2 = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";

$.when($.getJSON(url), $.getJSON(url2)).done(function (data1, data2) {

    alert(data1[0].address.village);
    alert(data2[0].address.city);

    //do stuff with 'data' and 'data2'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=15&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";
var url2 = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&lat=45.9660047&lon=13.6408311";


var data = {};

$.getJSON(url, function(result){
  data.data1 = result;
});

$.getJSON(url2, function(result){
  data.data2 = result;
});


console.log(data); // will return the two urls json code
```

You can try the code on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/qtcvux31/)

Comment: you should look into the definition of async and sync calls ... your code will never work as you have in your answer! `console.log(data)`  will always be `undefined`